# Retrieve unpackaged and installed managed package components in a zip file

Tags: managed-package, soap-api, metadata-api

I actually know how to retrieve zip for unpackaged components through RetrieveRequest object. I now want to retrieve unpackaged components as well as all installed packaged components(Installed packages may differ with none to many with names not known).

Is it possible through API? If yes , how can I do this via API call?

Comment: I stumbled upon your question and found a similar question with an in depth answer that you will likely find interesting: [How to get a list of the managed packages (including version numbers) installed in an org?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13561/how-to-get-a-list-of-the-managed-packages-including-version-numbers-installed?rq=1)

Answer (score 6):

According to the [RetrieveRequest](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_retrieve_request.htm):

> `packageNames`
>
> A list of package names to be retrieved. If you are retrieving only
>   unpackaged components, do not specify a name here. **You can retrieve
>   packaged and unpackaged components in the same retrieve.**

So, the method `packageNames` is what you are looking for. You just need to pass it a list of packaged names. Now, in terms of actually finding all of the package names, that is another issue in itself and I am not sure how to solve it.

Comment: you are right about using packageNames and i used it too passing a hard-coded list of package names. My real question is the last part of your answer which you are not sure of.

Comment: use the listMetadata call and set the ListMetadataQuery `type` parameter to InstalledPackage you can get a list of all managed packages.

Comment: @DanielBlackhall Using FileProperties object( let's say fp ) , fp.getFullName() and fp.getNamespacePrefix() returns me SFGA for a Package named "Salesforce for Google AdWords". Is there any way i can get Package Name?

Comment: The reason i want package name is , I have to retrieve components of all Installed Packages and for that i have to pass list of "Package names" to retrieveRequest object. It doesn't take namespace prefix but the name itself. I tested it by passing hard-coded list myself and it worked.

Comment: @user1986059 you're right, packageNames doesn't accept the namespace (or the package id which I also checked) And I can find no way to get the full text name of the managed package.

Answer (score 6):

I have been thinking on this question for a few days now, and decided it must be possible. The reason being is that the Force.com IDE is able to retrieve the metadata for each installed Managed Package.

[image: Force.com IDE Referenced Packages]

So I decompiled the IDE, hoping to uncover how the IDE gets a list of Managed Packages and their metadata. What I found was a SOQL query on an object that is not publicly exposed (according to the workbench schema browser).

> SELECT Id, Name, Description, IsManaged, VersionName FROM InstalledPackageVersion

I didn't confirm, but I assume with the results of this query the `packageNames` parameter of a metadata retrieve call can be populated.
If I try an execute this query in the Developer Console I get the error:

> sObject type 'InstalledPackageVersion' is not supported.

All this leads me to believe there is some black magic being performed in the IDE, and that unfortunately the answer to your question is that no it is not possible to get a list of `packageNames` values that can be used for the parameter in the metadata retrieve call.

Answer (score 3):

To get a list of the installed package names you can use the [listMetadata](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_listmetadata.htm) call.

You will want to set the ListMetadataQuery to **InstalledPackage**

---

As per [How do i retrieve all installed packages names through API?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13883/how-do-i-retrieve-all-installed-packages-names-through-api?rq=1)

I don't think you can get the full managed package name via the [FileProperties](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_retrieveresult.htm#retrieveresult_fileproperties) that are returned by listMetadata.

A work around would be to screen scrap the HTML from the Installed Packages page.
I.e. send a request to https://instance.salesforce.com/0A3 with the session ids in a cookie and then parse the package names out of the resulting HTML.

Remember that doing this isn't supported by Salesforce and could easily break if they make changes to the page.

Comment: I did tried this out. Using FileProperties object( let's say fp ) I am still not able to get package name. I tried fp.getFullName() , it returns the namespace prefix. For e.g Package Name: "Salesforce for Google AdWords" has namespace prefix "SFGA". I got SFGA in return of fp.getFullName() and fp.getNamespacePrefix(). Is there any way i can get package name "Salesforce for Google AdWords" ?

Answer (score 2):

> All this leads me to believe there is some black magic being performed in the IDE, and that unfortunately the answer to your question is that no it is not possible to get a list of packageNames values that can be used for the parameter in the metadata retrieve call.

The magic involved seems to be setting the client name on the connection, like this (using Java):

```
CallOptions_element header = new CallOptions_element();
header.setClient("apex_eclipse/27.0.201302151147");
connection.__setCallOptions(header);
```

EDIT: Simplified the code:

```
connection.setCallOptions("apex_eclipse/27.0.201302151147", "");
```

This makes the query run without the "sObject type 'InstalledPackageVersion' is not supported." error, although I only get an empty result, but that's probably because of some other error on my end. I'm currently investigating.

Comment: WOW, nice reverse engineering on the black magic - thanks for signing up to share!

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the namespaceprefix infront of the components you want to retrieve for example if i am retrieving good object and my namespaceprefix of the installed package object is bad you should specify bad_*good*_c.