# Client Orgs SF License details Using Apex

Tags: apex

We have a requirement to capture all the clients(different SF orgs) SF licensing information.We also need to capture some of the installed package information too along with the SF licensing info.
We would have all the credential details of the SF orgs in our system.
I would use SOAP API webservices to log into these SF orgs, 
but :
1. how would i get the SF licensing information for these SF orgs?
2. How would i get the managed package information?

Answer (score 0):

1) In order to get the licensing information you'll need to query the [UserLicense](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_userlicense.htm) object

2) [Here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13561/how-to-get-a-list-of-the-managed-packages-including-version-numbers-installed) is a detailed answer on how to retrieve managed package information