# Package Version Settings for Bulk API?

Tags: managed-package, bulk-api

Is there any way to specify Package Version Settings when uploading data via the Bulk API? I am familiar with the capabilities with the [SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/calls_package_versions.htm) but need to find something similar for the Bulk API.

I am working with an integration that uses the Bulk API and a Managed Package. Different versions of the managed package could have different sets of fields and the Bulk API could fail if the package has not been updated to include the new fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see any indication that the [Bulk API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_reference_schema.htm) supports dependencies on a specific package version in the same way that the SOAP Partner API does. It can specify the APIVersion, but that isn't what you are after.

There is the [default partner package version settings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/calls_package_versions.htm) set under **Develop | API**. I believe these are only for the Enterprise and Partner API.

I suspect you will need to use the Metadata API to first determine the installed packages and the corresponding versions. Then the code can adapt to the know schema for each version. See [How to get a list of the managed packages (including version numbers) installed in an org?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/13561/102)

Alternatively, use the field meta data that is available via the Partner API to determine which fields are present in the current org.