# How to find out list of appExchange installed packages that user have access using Apex?

Tags: apex, package-install

I want to show details about, what all AppExchange installed packages that user have access to on a Visualforce page, how could I get those details?

Comment: You can perform SOQL on Objects like [PackageLicense](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_packagelicense.htm) and [UserPackageLicense](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_userpackagelicense.htm) for getting desired result.

Comment: Check this link https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13561/how-to-get-a-list-of-the-managed-packages-including-version-numbers-installed